# How to graph a double quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I graph this kind of equation?
$$\ ax^2+bxy+cy^2=d $$

Comment: You have two unknowns and one equation, you can only find how $y$ depends on $x$ and vice versa

Comment: Our teacher asked us to solve 13x^2+18xy+37y^2=40 and I thought there might be an algorithm or smth to solve this.

Comment: That's the equation of a conic curve: an ellipse or a hyperbola.

Comment: Graphing is easy using [Graph](http://www.padowan.dk). If you want to do by hand then you can do it as Andreas showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating $x$ like a constant gives you the solution:

$$
cy^2+bxy+ax^2-d=0\\
y^2+\frac{bx}{c}y+\frac{ax^2-d}{c}=0
$$
so, with  the p-q-Formula
$$
y = -\frac{bx}{2c} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{bx}{2c}\right)^2-\frac{ax^2-d}{c}}
$$